# How to disable edge touchpanel gestures in gnome 3.14

Tags: touchscreen, gestures, gnome-shell, fedora-21

I am writing Qt app, and I want to make left screen edge gestures, but it is conflicting with gnome touch screen [gestures](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.14/touchscreen-gestures.html.en).
I have tried all posible gnome extensions, tweak tools...
I need to disable it, anyone knows how to disable these gestures?
PC: Fedora 21, Gnome 3.14.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've built this extension based on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896556/) that does what you need.

- [Disable Gestures](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1140/disable-gestures/)

If you'd like to know exactly how I did it:

1. Created a new Gnome Extension using `gnome-shell-extension-tool --create-extension`
2. Used the code from the top answer in [#36896556](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896556/) on `extension.js`, thanks to @kepler_kingsnake
3. Zipped it and uploaded it to Gnome Extensions
4. Realised there was a bunch of unnecessary code from the extension tool and removed it :)